# Method within a method (homework assignment)

Tags: java

I have a homework assignment where I am asked to:

> Write a method `sort(int[] arr)` that takes an integer array and uses a
>   method from a previous exercise to determine if the array is sorted in
>   increasing order or not. If it is already sorted, it should return the
>   array, if it is not, the method should sort the array before returning
>   it.

My problem is that I don't know how I should approach this assignment? Should I modify the previous method, call it within a new method or can I create a method within the method?
This is the previous method that I wrote:

```
public static void isSorted(int[] checkArray) {
    boolean isSorted = true;
    for (int i = 1; i < checkArray.length; i++) {
        if (checkArray[i - 1] > checkArray[i]) {
            isSorted = false;
```

Thanx in advance

Comment: You can't declare methods within methods. Your assignment is telling you to use a method from a previous exercise to check if the array is sorted in increasing order or not. Use it.

Comment: `public void bar() { foo(); }` I call the `foo()` method from my `bar()` method. Same concept as your assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the interest of you actually learning something, here's my solution:

```
public int[] sort(int[] arr) {
    if (!isSorted(arr))
        Arrays.sort(arr);
    return arr;
}
```

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int[])) is the documentation for `Arrays.sort`

Not only is this more concise, it also does the sort in-place.  This means that instead of copying the array you pass in, doing the work, and then returning the copy, it just does the work on the original array.  This makes it slightly faster and means it takes up a minimal amount of extra space.  Not that big a deal when your input size is 10, but it is when you get to 10 million.  Also, note the wording of the assignment: `If it is already sorted, it should return the array, if it is not, the method should sort the array before returning it.`  Technically, returning a *copy* of the original array is not what the assignment wants.  It wants the original.

So it's short, clean, fast, and memory efficient.  It must be good, right?

No, because it has one huge flaw.  It breaks the implied contract of the method.  A function that changes its arguments should not return anything, and a function that returns something should not modify its arguments.  This is a basic principle of software engineering (and one that Arrays.sort demonstrates).  Violating this can cause huge problems for those who assume you're competent and won't break this rule.

If we follow the rule, `sort` should be this:

```
public void sort(int[] arr) {
    if (!isSorted(arr))
        Arrays.sort(arr);
}
```

So tell your teacher an armored hamster you met on the Internet said to stop teaching you poor interface design.

Comment: Thank you very much! This seems like a better approach. I will definitely tell him that haha.

Answer (score 1):

I read "uses [the] method" to mean "calls the method". That said, testing for sortedness before sorting seems somewhat pointless, so it might be worth double-checking with whoever gave you that assignment.

One issue with your previous method is that it doesn't return anything. You'll need to do something about that to make it useful.

Comment: There are certain sorting algorithms that perform very poorly on sorted data, so doing a sanity check beforehand is reasonable.

Comment: True. In the actual assignment I am invoking the method and printing the result.

Comment: @Floegipoky: Point taken. And, again, it's only an exercise after all.

Comment: I think the point is just learning how to do it regardless of it being pointless. So what should I do in practice? I know how to use the java.util.Arrays.sort method but my problem is combining the method that I already wrote with a new method that returns the array or sorts it...

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want to do:

```java
public int[] sort(int[] arr)
{
    if (isSorted(arr))
        return arr;
    else
    {
         \\Your sorting code here

         return sorted_array;
    }
}
```